# Mysql random select giving unexpected result

Tags: mysql

I am trying to select 4 random names from my table. Here is my query:

```
SELECT RAND() FROM tbl_name ORDER BY id LIMIT 4;
```

This is output I am getting
[image]

My table structure:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
SELECT name FROM tbl_name ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 4;
```